# How to store external social media account linking in the database?

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0

Let's say we have a backend in ExpressJS. We are using simple BcryptJS to hash and store passwords and emails in the database.
Now I want to add the link social media accounts feature like this:
[image]

Now what I was wondering is what should I store in the database? Like lets say I registered using email and password, now I go in settings and add Google login, what should I store with the user's record in the database to use the Google identity in the future when needed? Like should I store the access token? the refresh token? Should I keep refreshing the token? Should I not even store the token?

Sorry if it might sound silly, but I googled around and didn't find the answer I wanted, and I have spent the last hour thinking about this. What do you guys think? And this answer might help a lost developer in the future too.

Answer (score 1):

**SOCIAL LOGINS**

If this is your starting point, and assuming that the email used from Google or Facebook matches that used when logging in with passwords:

| Field | Example Value |
| --- | --- |
| User ID | 203 |
| Email | john@company.com |

Then when you receive the Google or Facebook response you would need to look for an email in it, either by inspecting the ID token or calling their user info endpoint. You can then match to the User ID that makes sense to your business data.

If you store anything from those providers it should be a linked record, something like this. You should only need to store access tokens from the third party provider if your app needs to access the user's Google or Facebook resources with it:

| Field | Example Value |
| --- | --- |
| User Link ID | 1039 |
| User ID | 203 |
| Provider | Google |
| Subject | d2ee68ee-7853-11ec-90d6-0242ac120003 |

**PROBLEM AREAS**

1. The above mechanism is inherently unreliable and can easily result in duplicate users in your business data, eg if the social provider does not give you an email and the user exists already in your business data. A technique to solve this problem can be to involve the user - ask them if they exist already in your app and if so then ask them to authenticate with an existing method (password in your case) as part of onboarding to social logins.
2. Foreign access tokens, from Google and Facebook, are not designed to be used to secure your own APIs - you may not even be able to validate them in some cases, and you will not be able to control claims and scopes. This leads some people to write custom code to issue their own tokens.

**AUTHORIZATION SERVER**

For future reference, the preferred architecture is for your UIs and APIs to only talk to your own Authorization Server, which is hosted alongside APIs. This component will then manage the following aspects for you, all of which will keep the security plumbing out of your apps:

- Login connections to social providers
- Dealing with provider specific differences
- Providing [account linking capabilities](https://curity.io/docs/idsvr/latest/authentication-service-admin-guide/account-linking/index.html)
- Storing linked records
- Allowing you to return your own customized tokens to your own apps
- In more advanced use cases the AS can also hold onto the third party access token for you via the [embedded token approach](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-sharing/#embedding-a-token).